# PYODBC - Type Error: the first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query

Tags: python-3.x

Been trying to connect our ERP ODBC by using PYODBC, Although I got the syntax correct the only error I'm getting at this point is this 'TypeError: the first argument to execute must be a string or  unicode query'

I've tried adding .decode('utf-8').

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd 

conn = pyodbc.connect(
                      'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                      'SERVER=192.168.1.30;'
                      'DATABASE=Datamart;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor() 
for row in cursor.tables(tableType='TABLE'): 
    print(row)
sql = """SELECT * FROM ETL.Dim_FC_UPS_Interface_Detail"""
cursor.execute(row, sql)

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your ordering of commands is off a bit for use of pyodbc cursor execute function. See the [docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters).

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = """SELECT * FROM ETL.Dim_FC_UPS_Interface_Detail"""
cursor.execute(sql)

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```